# Getting error Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values when adding JToken

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following structure of additional information where I need to update the value of one of the tokens in the structure. The data is an array of JTokens with a parent called 'additionalFields' as follows:

```
{{"additionalFields": 
[
{ "name": "NAME1", "value": "VALUE1" },
{ "name": "NAME2", "value": "VALUE2" },
{ "name": "NAME3", "value": "VALUE3" },
{ "name": "NAME4", "value": "VALUE4" }
]}
```

I'm trying to update the value of one of the tokens e.g. to change VALUE1 to VALUE10.

Once I have located the token I need to update my code removes it as follows.

```
additionalField.Remove();
```

I then create a new token to replace the one I have removed (containing the new value) using the following functions.

```
public static JToken CreateNewToken(string name, string value)
{
    var stringToken = CreateNewStringToken(name, value);
    var token = JToken.Parse(stringToken);
     return (JToken) token;
}

private static string CreateNewStringToken(string name, string value)
{
    return $"{{\"name\":\"{name}\",\"value\":\"{value}\"}}";
}
```

I then add the new token as follows.

```
additionalFields.AddAfterSelf(updatedToken);
```

Putting it all together we have the following

```
foreach (var additionalField in additionalFields)
{
    //is this the key we are looking for?
    var keyToken = additionalField.First;

    if (keyToken?.First == null) continue;
    if (string.Equals(keyToken.First.ToString(), "newname", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        //remove the current token
        additionalField.Remove();
        
        //add the updated token
        var updatedToken = CreateNewToken("newname", "newvalue");
        additionalFields.AddAfterSelf(updatedToken); <-- error occurs here!!
    }
}
```

However after adding the token I'm getting the following error

**Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values**

I can see in the debugger that the token has been removed (as the token.Count is reduced by 1) so cannot understand why I'm getting an error adding the replacement token.

Comment: Please show **all** the relevant code.

Comment: Added additional code which hopefully gives a better idea of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JIVCVB

#### What is going wrong

`additionalFields` refers to the JArray of JObjects containing `name` and `value` JProperties.  You are looping through this JArray to try to find the first JObject having a `name` property with a certain value, and when you find it you attempt to replace the JObject with a whole new JObject.  You successfully remove the old JObject from the JArray, but when you are doing `AddAfterSelf` to insert the new JObject, you are referencing `additionalFields` (plural) not `additionalField` (singular).  Recall that `additionalFields` is the JArray.  So you are saying that you want to add the new JObject *after* the array.  The array's parent is a JProperty called `additionalFields`.  A JProperty can only have one value, so `AddAfterSelf` fails with the error you see.

#### How to fix your code

I think what you intended to do was `additionalField.AddAfterSelf(updatedToken)`. However, this, too, will fail, for a different reason: you already removed the `additionalField` from the JArray at that point, so it no longer has a parent context.  You would need to `AddAfterSelf` *before* you remove the item you are trying to insert after.  If you fix that, you still have another problem: your loop doesn't break out after you've done the replacement, so then you will get an error about modifying the collection while looping over it.

Here is the relevant section of code with the corrections:

```
if (string.Equals(keyToken.First.ToString(), "NAME1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    //add the updated token
    var updatedToken = CreateNewToken("newname", "newvalue");
    additionalField.AddAfterSelf(updatedToken);

    //remove the current token
    additionalField.Remove();
    
    // we found what we were looking for so no need to continue looping
    break; 
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KcFsZc

#### A simpler approach

You seem to be jumping through a lot of hoops to accomplish this task.  Instead of looping, you can use `FirstOrDefault` to find the object you are looking for in the array.  Once you've found it, you don't need to replace the whole object; you can just update the property values directly.

Here's how:

```
var rootObject = JToken.Parse(json);

// Get a reference to the array of objects as before
var additionalFields = rootObject["additionalFields"];

// Find the object we need to change in the array
var additionalField = additionalFields.FirstOrDefault(f => 
    string.Equals((string)f["name"], "NAME1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

// if the object is found, update its properties
if (additionalField != null)
{
    additionalField["name"] = "newname";
    additionalField["value"] = "newvalue";
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZAKRmi

Comment: Wow that was a brilliant response to my question, and you've clearly explained the mis-understanding I had trying to iterate over the JSON object. Many thanks for taking the time to so clearly explain all this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries; glad I could help!